# How to return html row data with a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Is there a way I can console.log a row's data on a select/dropdown event? For example, here is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none;"></th>
                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Item Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each context.order_item}}
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">{{id}}</td>
                <td>{{product_code}}</td>
                <td>{{brand}}</td>
                <td>{{category}}</td>
                <td>{{description}}</td>
                <td>{{quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{invoice_price}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="item_status" class="item_status">
                        <option selected>{{status}}</option>
                        <option>Order Confirmed</option>
                        <option>Order Completed</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel Item</button></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I click my select dropdown, I want it to console.log the value of 'Brand'.. Pseudocode:

```
$("#.item_status").change(function() {
    console.log(this.row.brand); //need to console.log the value of brand in this row
});
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it will always be the 3rd cell of the row, you can do this:

```
 $(".item_status").change(function() {
   var brnd = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).html()
   console.log(brnd)
 }
```

also, no `#` on the class selector
Fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/sx1c9xpz/

Comment: gotcha, but what if it isn't always the 3rd row?

Comment: well, you would need some other way to identify the cell - your table appears to always have the brand in the 3rd cell